# Bitwise operations, ulong and int

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I just discovered that C# will not let you perform bitwise operations on a `ulong` and an `int`.  Every other combination of `int`, `uint`, `long`, and `ulong` will work, but that one pairing doesn't.

*However*, if instead of an `int`, I have a `const int`, everything is fine.

What's going on here?  Why is `int & ulong` invalid, but `const int & ulong` valid?

---

Broken:

```
int mask = 0x1110;
ulong value = 0x1010;

var result = mask & value; // Compilation error: "Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'ulong'"
```

Working:

```
const int mask = 0x1110;
ulong value = 0x1010;

var result = mask & value; // Works just fine.
```

Comment: Can you show some code that works and some that doesn't ?

Comment: @Feel fee to show a code. What kind of operations you executes on that types

Comment: The `const int` might be casted on compiletime.

Comment: @MartinVerjans - Added.

Comment: Another pairs with the same behavior are `ulong` and `short`; `ulong` and `sbyte`

Comment: If you are doing bitwise operations I would use unsigned numbers not signed.  Doing a bitwise of signed number will create issues with 2's compliment sign extension.

Comment: @jdweng - That definitely sounds like a good reason to prohibit combining a signed type with a larger unsigned one.  Doesn't address why a constant is fine, though. (Also, good advice in general)

Comment: I'm surprised that *either* version is allowed without explicit casts. `ulong` and `int` are different sizes (number of bytes). Performing bitwise operations on different sized operands is nonsensical. Also, bitwise operations between signed and unsigned operands should really be avoided.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work if the `const` is set to a negative number.  I guess it's allowing it because it knows the `int` cannot be negative.

Comment: @DavidLively C# language specification allows the compiler to promote a `const int` to `ulong` when compiler knows that the value stays the same after the conversion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behavior is not specific to bitwise operations. According to *C# Language Specification*, it applies to all binary operations requiring *numeric promotions*.

Section 7.6.3.2 describes binary numeric promotions. I emphasized the section that specifies the behavior that you see:

> Binary numeric promotion consists of applying the following rules, in the order they appear here:
>
> - If either operand is of type `decimal`, the other operand is converted to type `decimal`, or a binding-time error occurs if the other operand is of type `float` or `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `double`, the other operand is converted to type `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other operand is converted to type `float`.
> - **Otherwise, if either operand is of type `ulong`, the other operand is converted to type `ulong`, or a binding-time error occurs if the other operand is of type `sbyte`, `short`, `int`, or `long`.**
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other operand is converted to type `long`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `uint` and the other operand is of type `sbyte`, `short`, or int, both operands are converted to type `long`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `uint`, the other operand is converted to type `uint`.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

The reason the problem does not happen when you use `const` is that the compiler is allowed to convert `const int` expression to other types, as described in section 7.19:

> An implicit constant expression conversion (§6.1.9) permits a constant expression of type `int` to be converted to `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, or `ulong`, provided the value of the constant expression is within the range of the destination type.

Since the value of `mask`, i.e. `0x1110`, fits within `ulong`, the compiler performs the promotion instead of triggering the error.

Comment: It all makes sense now!  Thank you.